# How to query mongo db to return all combinations of keys in a search term?

Tags: regex, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

In the mongo db are tags. I'm trying to pull out all the tags that would match starting from the beginning of a search term. Is it possible to achieve the following in a mongo query?

Mongo data:

```json
[
  { tag: '123' },
  { tag: '1234' },
  { tag: '123456' },
  { tag: '987' },
  { tag: '555' }
]
```

Query search term = '12349339'

Result desired:

```json
[
  { tag: '123'},
  { tag: '1234' }
]
```

or

```json
[
  { tag: '1234' }
]
```

I've tried regex expressions to no avail as using (^) would only be useful if the longer search term was in the db and I was searching using a substring.

**Update**: Here's my regex attempt for anyone trying this approach.

> tags.find({tag: {$regex: '^12349339*'}})

Returns nothing. If I wanted all tags that match '123' then this kind of query would work.

> tags.find({tag: {$regex: '^123'}})

Returns:

```json
[
  { tag: '123' },
  { tag: '1234' },
  { tag: '123456' }
]
```

But I wanted the reverse. So, figured I needed an aggregate function or something.

Comment: Hi Rich - could you describe the queries you've tried so far, and the results they have given?

Comment: I've tried using combinations of regex like { $regex: '^12349339' } but these are for the reverse of what I want. Wake's answer is promising.

Comment: if you have extra information to add in response to a comment for example, you should improve your question by editing the question to include the extra info.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Vince. However, my question did state that I tried regex using the ^ statement but that wasn't appropriate for the task. So basically I hit a wall and was asking for some direction on strategy. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I mean it's useful to literally paste in an example of an actual query you've tried, and what the results were, and why that wasn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
{
    $where: "'12349339'.indexOf(this.tag) == 0"
}
```

Obligatory performance note on using $where: The $where provides greater flexibility, but requires that the database processes the JavaScript expression or function for each document in the collection. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Comment: Nice, this works. I'll see if I can shave down the result set the $where searches to speed it up. Thanks.